# Customer information not displayed in header after login

Tags: magento2, customer, header

I am logged in my local machine as customer and magento header not displaying the name of logged in user.

I am also tried to add product but cart is empty.

Give me your suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: Have you checked in console? Facing any issue?

Comment: update your url which is use in local machine

Answer (score 1):

Update your host file.

> /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost

And also update your database table "core_config_data"
web/unsecure/base_url "http://localhost/magento226/" to "http://127.0.0.1/magento226/"
web/secure/base_url "http://localhost/magento226/" to "http://127.0.0.1/magento226/"

Then after please follow below command:

```
rm -rf generated/metadata/ generated/code/ var/cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/page_cache/ var/composer_home/ pub/static/frontend/
```